# Why does QFontDialog.getFont() always return the same font?

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, qfont

Every time I use `QFontDialog.getFont()` to get a font, it returns the same `QFont` object.

```
font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont()
print(font)
if ok:
    self.lbl.setFont(font)
print(self.lbl.font())
```

Above is the code segment, and the result is below (I make different choices but the font of the `QLabel` and the font I get from `getFont()` is always the same one).

```
/Users/yao/PycharmProjects/QT_test/venv/bin/python /Users/yao/PycharmProjects/QT_test/test/4_2.py
<PyQt5.QtGui.QFont object at 0x10b428748>
<PyQt5.QtGui.QFont object at 0x10b4287b8>
<PyQt5.QtGui.QFont object at 0x10b428748>
<PyQt5.QtGui.QFont object at 0x10b4287b8>
```

---

**Update**:

Below is some information about my environment:

- macOS Mojave
- PyQt5
- Python 3.6

I have tested the codes by @ekhumoro and the results are strange:

```
BEFORE:
  string:.SF NS Text, 13,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
  family:.SF NS Text
   size:13

AFTER:
  string:.SF NS Text, 13,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
  family:.SF NS Text
   size:13
```

Comment: It gives you a `QFont` object at the same location in memory.. whats the result of `print(self.lbl.font().toString())`?

Comment: A `QFont` is used for ***requesting*** a font from the system. There is never any guarantee that you will get exactly what you asked for. You should always use `QFontInfo` to get information about the actual font that has been provided by the system.

Comment: Well, I have used the method toString() to get the description of the font, and it yields the same result: .SF NS Text,13,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

This seems to be caused by a bug that only affects macOS: see [QTBUG-6071](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-6071) and [QTBUG-69878](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69878). This should have been fixed in Qt-5.12, so you need to make sure you've installed the latest versions of both Qt5 and PyQt5 in order to resolve this issue.

---

Below is a test script with some screenshots of the output I get on Linux using Qt-5.12.0 with PyQt- 5.11.3. As you can see, everything works as expected. If you get different behaviour, you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54492063/edit) and state the exact versions of Qt and PyQt you are using, which platform you are testing on, and show some sample output from the test script.

**Test Script**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Change Font')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.updateLabel)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.updateLabel()

    def updateLabel(self):
        if self.label.text():
            new = QtWidgets.QFontDialog.getFont()[0]
        else:
            new = QtGui.QFont(self.label.font())
        before = self.label.font()
        self.label.setFont(new)
        after = self.label.font()
        text = []
        for font in before, after:
            info = QtGui.QFontInfo(font)
            text.append('BEFORE:' if font is before else 'AFTER:')
            text.append('  string: %s' % font.toString())
            text.append('  family: %s' % info.family())
            text.append('    size: %s' % info.pointSize())
            text.append('')
        text = '\n'.join(text)
        self.label.setText(text)
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 500, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Output**:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have tested the codes you posted, and I have updated this question with the result. I guess the reason that I get the same output may be my OS, but I'm not sure because I  don't get relative information about this.

Comment: @Yao See my updated answer. There seems to be a bug that only affects macOS. If you update your qt and pyqt installation to the latest versions, it should be fixed. (PS: if you found this answer useful, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick symbol above).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have checked versions of my QT and PyQt. I'm using PyQt(5.11.3) and QT(5.9.7). However, my QT is bundled with Anaconda, so I'm afraid that something there won't work properly if I update my QT. So I can't check this answer, but now I do know that it's an uncommon problem with macOS. Again, thanks for your test codes and issues about this bug, and I have marked this answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

`<PyQt5.QtGui.QFont object at 0x10b4287b8>` only gives you the location in memory of your object, it's basically a memory cell number, but in hexadecimal. You can have a different object (here, a different QFont object), stored in the same memory space.

You could check that the QFont object here is the one you selected by doing this:

```
font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont()
print(font.toString())
```

> Update: Could you try the following code and tell us what you get?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication, QDialog, QVBoxLayout

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

dlg = QDialog()
layout = QVBoxLayout()

for fontname in ["Verdana", "Arial", "Consolas"]:
    widget = QLabel(fontname)
    font = QFont(fontname)
    widget.setFont(font)
    layout.addWidget(widget)

dlg.setLayout(layout)
dlg.show()

r = app.exec_()
```

Comment: .SF NS Text,13,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
I have used the method toString(), and I get the same output before the if segment and after that.

Comment: @Yao Why do you think it should be different? And why does it matter? Are you saying that the label does not render the font correctly?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes. The setFont() method seems to be invalid, and the appearance of this label doesn't change at all.

Comment: I added a working example of use of various fonts, could you try it?

Comment: @Yao It all works exactly as expected for me. Please try the test script in my answer.

Comment: @olinox14 Thanks for your test codes. I have tested the codes. I don't know how to describe my window, but the three labels within the window seem to be same...I  also tested codes by ekhumoro, and I have update this question and include description about the appearance.